# Nested Attributes with Rails 4 Strong Parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user

  has_many :attachments
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachments 

end

class DocumentsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @document = get_user.documents.build
    3.times { @document.attachments.build }
  end

  def create
    @document = Document.new post_params
  end

  def post_params
    params.require(:document).permit(:id, :subject, :body, attachments_attributes:[:attachment])
  end

end
```

_form.html.slim

```
  = f.fields_for :attachments do |builder|
    = builder.file_field :attachment, multiple: true
```

Here is the problem:

The attachments on my `post_params` are empty:

```
{"id"=>"", "to"=>"5621", "subject"=>"Hello", "body"=>"World", "attachments_attributes"=>{"0"=>{}}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is the way to do it:

```
  def post_params
    params.require(:document).permit(:id, :subject, :body, attachments_attributes:[:attachment => []])
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be missing `multipart: true` on your form tag.

Comment: This is not the problem

Answer (score 0):

possibly

```
def post_params
  params.require(:document).permit(:id, :subject, :body,
                                   attachments_attributes: ['0'])
end
```

Comment: But there are an unlimited amount of attachments.